# Query Index question

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, index-tuning

I am trying to figure out how I can index this query below. The table is 155 columns. It has a clustered index on the column which is not in the query. The query is dynamically created from out of the box application and no way I cant tune it except adding index. I could not find an index that will optimize the query. The table has 511919 rows.Now, it is clustered index scan OR non clustered index Scan (with covered index)

SQL Server version : 2016 SP2, We have 22 core and 24 gbs on the server. I can post a query plan.

```
    Declare
        @P0 VARCHAR(8000)
        ,@P1 VARCHAR(8000)
        ,@P2 VARCHAR(8000)
        ,@P3 VARCHAR(8000)
        ,@P4 INT
        ,@P5 VARCHAR(8000)
        ,@P6 VARCHAR(8000)
        ,@P7 VARCHAR(8000)
        ,@P8 INT
        ,@P9 VARCHAR(8000)

Set @P0 = 'Cancelled'
Set @P1 ='20190321'
Set @P2 ='20190321'
Set @P3 ='20190321'
Set @P5 ='20190321'
Set @P6 ='20190321'
Set @P7 ='20190321'

Set @P4 =1
Set @P8 =0

Set @P9='Service'

SELECT  Col1,
    Col2,
    Col3,
    Col4,
    Col5,
    Col6,
    Col7,
    Col8,
    Col9,
    Col10,
    Col11,
    Col12,
    Col13,
    Col14,
    Col15,
    Col16,
    Col17,
    Col18,
    Col19,
    Col20,
    Col21,
    Col22,
    Col23,
    Col24,
    Col25,
    Col26,
    Col27,
    Col28,
    Col29,
    Col30,
    Col31,
    Col32,
    Col33,
    Col34,
    Col35,
    Col36,
    Col37
FROM Table1
WHERE (
        Col18 IS NOT NULL
        AND Col75 <> @P0
        AND DATEDIFF(dd, Col146, CAST(SUBSTRING(@P1, 1, 4) + '-' + SUBSTRING(@P2, 5, 2) + '-' + SUBSTRING(@P3, 7, 2) + 'T00:00:00.000' AS DATETIME)) <= @P4
        AND DATEDIFF(dd, Col146, CAST(SUBSTRING(@P5, 1, 4) + '-' + SUBSTRING(@P6, 5, 2) + '-' + SUBSTRING(@P7, 7, 2) + 'T00:00:00.000' AS DATETIME)) >= @P8
        )
    AND Col39 = @P9
ORDER BY 18 ASC
    ,31 DESC
    ,30 ASC
```

This is a covered index. It is used as non clustered index Scan.

```
/****** Object:  Index [NC_OBJ_DID_SQ_CoveredIndex2]    Script Date: 3/21/2019 1:30:31 PM ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX NC1 ON Table1
(
    TableCol39  ASC,
    TableCol6 ASC,
    TableCol75  ASC,
    TableCol18  ASC
)
INCLUDE (   TableCol1,
    TableCol2,
    TableCol3,
    TableCol4,
    TableCol5,
    TableCol6,
    TableCol7,
    TableCol8,
    TableCol9,
    TableCol10,
    TableCol11,
    TableCol12,
    TableCol13,
    TableCol14,
    TableCol15,
    TableCol17,
    TableCol19,
    TableCol20,
    TableCol21,
    TableCol22,
    TableCol23,
    TableCol24,
    TableCol25,
    TableCol26,
    TableCol27,
    TableCol28,
    TableCol29,
    TableCol30,
    TableCol31,
    TableCol32,
    TableCol33,
    TableCol34,
    TableCol35,
    TableCol36,
    TableCol37,
    TablCol146 ) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Please consider reading [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions).

Comment: `(Col39, Col18, Col75) INCLUDE (Col146)`

Comment: Hi, Posting the query plan to Pastetheplan.com would help. You should also stray away from ordering with numbers. It is best to put the column names in the order clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If you are unable to adapt the queries, some of these columns in the where clause will remain not sargable.**

To make your query sargable, You would need to try and remove the `DATEADD()` functions in the where clause, around `Col146`. 
This makes the (possible) index on `Col146` not sargable.

Consider this as a possible change:

```
AND Col146 <= DATEADD(dd,-@P4,CAST(SUBSTRING(@P1, 1, 4) + '-' + SUBSTRING(@P2, 5, 2) + '-' + SUBSTRING(@P3, 7, 2) + 'T00:00:00.000' AS DATETIME)) 
AND Col146 >= DATEADD(dd,-@P8,CAST(SUBSTRING(@P1, 1, 4) + '-' + SUBSTRING(@P2, 5, 2) + '-' + SUBSTRING(@P3, 7, 2) + 'T00:00:00.000' AS DATETIME))
```

Making sure that all functions are applied to the variables. You should not take my word for it and double check this.

**Index changes.**

If you could make your query sargable & the sort is not expensive.

```
CREATE INDEX IX_Table1_Col39_Col146_Col75
ON Table1(Col39,Col146,Col75)
INCLUDE(Col18 
,Col31 
,Col30 )
WHERE Col18  IS NOT NULL
```

**However**, If a lot of rows are returned after the search predicates, you might have to index your `SORT` (`Order by`) As well, since that one will use a lot of CPU depending on the  amount of rows passing through. We would have to see an actual query plan to determine this.

---

**We are not able to change the query, no matter how much we beg and plead for mercy**

You could try and index that what is sargable and try to remove the `SORT` operator.

```
CREATE INDEX IX_Table1_Col39_Col75_Col18_Col31_Col30
ON Table1(Col39 ASC ,Col75 ASC ,Col18 ASC,Col31 DESC, Col30 ASC)
INCLUDE(  Col146 )
WHERE Col18  IS NOT NULL;
```

Note that the <> operator is [not that sargable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15483508/is-sargable-or-not-if-not-what-can-i-use-instead), you could probably try and change it to;

```
CREATE INDEX IX_Table1_Col39_Col146_Col75
ON Table1(Col39 ASC ,Col18 ASC,Col31 DESC, Col30 ASC)
INCLUDE(  Col146,Col75 )
WHERE Col18  IS NOT NULL;
```

**What about the other columns?**

The include list is something I will leave to you, depending on the expected resultset's, the `key lookup` could be something to live with or not.

The optimizer might not even use the index if it thinks that the `key lookup` would be too expensive.

---

**Testing the theories**

To see if what I am saying holds any truth, I conducted a test, ofcourse, YMMV. It is simply to see if it is even possible to remove  the `SORT` operator and that we are able to seek on certain filters.

DDL + DML Below.

**Index #1**

```
CREATE INDEX IX_Table1_Col39_Col75_Col18_Col31_Col30
ON Table1(Col39 ASC ,Col75 ASC ,Col18 ASC,Col31 DESC, Col30 ASC)
INCLUDE(  Col146 )
WHERE Col18  IS NOT NULL;
```

While we are able to seek on col75 and col39, the sort + residual predicate remains:

[image]

And that is not what was expected unfortunately.

**There is light at the end of the Tunnel (Index #2)**

```
CREATE INDEX IX_Table1_Col39_Col18_Col31_Col30
ON Table1(Col39 ASC  ,Col18 ASC,Col31 DESC, Col30 ASC)
INCLUDE(  Col146,Col75)
WHERE Col18  IS NOT NULL;
```

I can rerun my **modified** test query (without all the selected columns)

```
         Declare
        @P0 VARCHAR(8000)
        ,@P1 VARCHAR(8000)
        ,@P2 VARCHAR(8000)
        ,@P3 VARCHAR(8000)
        ,@P4 INT
        ,@P5 VARCHAR(8000)
        ,@P6 VARCHAR(8000)
        ,@P7 VARCHAR(8000)
        ,@P8 INT
        ,@P9 VARCHAR(8000)


Set @P0 = '1blabla'
Set @P1 ='20190315'
Set @P2 ='20190315'
Set @P3 ='20190315'
Set @P5 ='20190315'
Set @P6 ='20190315'
Set @P7 ='20190315'

SET @P9 = '0bla'
Set @P4 =1
Set @P8 =1
SELECT *
FROM table1 Where
(
 Col18 IS NOT NULL
        AND Col75 <> @P0
           AND DATEDIFF(dd, Col146, CAST(SUBSTRING(@P1, 1, 4) + '-' + SUBSTRING(@P2, 5, 2) + '-' + SUBSTRING(@P3, 7, 2) + 'T00:00:00.000' AS DATETIME)) <= @P4
        AND DATEDIFF(dd, Col146, CAST(SUBSTRING(@P5, 1, 4) + '-' + SUBSTRING(@P6, 5, 2) + '-' + SUBSTRING(@P7, 7, 2) + 'T00:00:00.000' AS DATETIME)) >= @P8

     )
    AND Col39 = @P9
ORDER BY Col18 ASC
    ,Col31 DESC
    ,Col30 ASC;
```

**To get a pretty seek with no sort or other operators *(And a pesky residual predicate.)***

[image]

Your result could look more like this:

[image]

**Conclusion**

Based on these tests, which may very well be 100% different for you, this is the index that I would initially go for:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_Table1_Col39_Col18_Col31_Col30
ON Table1(Col39 ASC  ,Col18 ASC,Col31 DESC, Col30 ASC)
INCLUDE(  Col146,Col75)
WHERE Col18  IS NOT NULL;
```

**DDL + DML Used in this example**

```
        SET NOCOUNT ON;
        DECLARE @i int = 0
        WHILE @i < 100
        BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Table1(Col39,   Col75,Col146,Col18,Col31,Col30)
        VALUES(cast(@i as varchar(3))+'bla',
               cast(@i as varchar(3))+'blabla',
               DATEADD(DD,-@i,GETDATE()),
               cast(@i as varchar(3))+'blablabla',
               cast(@i as varchar(3))+'blablablabla',
               cast(@i as varchar(3))+'blablablablabla');
        SET @i += 1;
        END
        SET NOCOUNT OFF ;
        INSERT INTO Table1
        SELECT * From Table1;
        GO 7
        Beginning execution loop

   (6500 rows)

    GO
```

Comment: Hi Randi, Wow! I am very impressed by your answers. I am going to test your theories and update you as soon as I can. Thank you so much for taking the time to look at the query. Since it is out of the box query, I am afraid that I can change the query. It is out of the box application query that constructs the date comparism part.

Comment: @AMMH Awesome, remember that my test was on meaningless fabricated data, and that people on the internet can be wrong. Having said that, I hope my theory helps you out! Good luck and will be awaiting your feedback!

Comment: hey @AMMH I am not entirely following but I think you got stuff worked out now? Could always add the query plan to the question if you need a second look.

Comment: Hi Randi, I removed DateDiff and added DateAdd to calculate the date. Modified the index to CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [TEST] ON Table1
 Col146 ASC,
 Col75 ASC,
 Col39 ASC,
 Col18 ASC,
 Col31 DESC,
 Col32 ASC
)
INCLUDE (  All columns in select) 
WHERE (Col18 IS NOT NULL) This time the index was seek 44% and sort is 55% in execution plan..

Comment: @AMMH, these percentages are based on estimates. Could be that either of those two is still the 'bad guy'. The last three key columns, `Col18 ASC, Col31 DESC, Col32 ASC` where added to remove the sort. But it is still staying in there, so for some reason it is not able to sort. Now, it depends on how many values that pass through the `sort operator` if we need to change this. Adding the query plan could help. Could be that the last index that worked for my example works for you to remove the sort. Will need to do some testing.

Comment: @AMMH the reason that I am saying this is that the ordering does not preserve when using filters like <>. That is why, on my example this index `CREATE INDEX IX_Table1_Col39_Col18_Col31_Col30
ON Table1(Col39 ASC, Col18 ASC,Col31 DESC, Col30 ASC)
INCLUDE(  Col146,Col75)
WHERE Col18  IS NOT NULL;` Did remove the  `sort ` but added the extra Predicate. So when a lot of data is filtered by the filter on  `Col146 ` and  `Col75 ` Then this index will probably not work.

Comment: Hi Randi, Thank you for your reply. i removed the filter and Col146,Col18,Col39,Col75,Col31 Desc, Col 30asc. Now, Seek predicate is the  date and Other columns are predicate. 6% seek and also Clustered index insert 85% CWT_Primary key. I tried to post execution plan here. It is dissappeared as soon as it is posted. Thank you Randi!

Comment: @AMMH Alright, great, If you found the solution that fits for you then you can post it as the answer so others do not need to try and find a solution, or if my index proposals worked for you then you can select mine as the answer. But it seems like you made some changes. No problem, thanks for getting back to me with all these updates!

Comment: @AMMH Great that it worked for you! No problem, happy to help!